# IE mouseleave event not contains right mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mouseleave

Can somebody help me?

Im trying to handle mouseleave event in js, and doing some login based from which parts (coordinates) window it leaves, actually e.clientX and e.clientY params.

Its correct work in Chrome/Safari/Firefox, but unfortunately not in IE.

In all version of IE, when mouse leave the window, e.clientX and e.clientY equals -1, and it disappoint me.

Does somebody met with this situation? And which is the best way to avoid it.

Thnks for you attention :)